# Symfony form and loop with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have recently started using Symfony.
I write a doctrine query and i  found the values I needed but i have the problem when i want to enter values in a form's textbox with a for loop.. 
This is my query:

```
 $id_user = $user->getId();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('ur','uu')   
     ->from('DtEcBundle:UserReferences', 'ur')
     ->innerJoin("ur.id_user","uu")
     ->where("ur.id_user = :id_user")
     ->setParameter("id_user",$id_user)
            ->getQuery();
            $userpyramid = $query->getResult();
```

And now i would insert my values in a form..

```
 $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('form', 'form')
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('profilo_secondlevel'))
        ->add('idreferenced', 'text', array(
                'data' =>  '',
            ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Prova'])
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: So .... what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I can not enter my values in a loop to print in a form and I can not convert the string array of my query.. 
i would print a value for each textbox, 1 value for 1 textbox. Sorry for my english

Comment: That is very unclear, I'm not sure I get what you want. Try to explain your problem more clearly and give us more details

Comment: I have a query.. the value of my query i would insert in a textbox with a loop in a form, 1 value in a 1 textbox.......... I can not do it

Comment: @LucaM: yes, this is very unclear. Do you want a line for each UserReferences fetched from db? If so, why are you selecting uu also? Are you planning to use it? Finally, what should appear into textbox?

Comment: I select 'uu' too because i work on UserReferences table like this user_references(id,id_user,id_user_referenced,reference) , id_user_referenced is related with 'id' from tabel user , i would in my form <label>Name Surname(from user tabel)</label> <input type="text"  value="id_user_referenced"/>  Ok??

Comment: @LucaM: are name and surname read only or editable? Moreover, why do you need id_user_referenced? Is only to show something or ... ?

Comment: Name and surname read only. i need id_user_referenced for create a form and send the value of 'id' in another page

Comment: @LucaM: I don't get it... What will you have to do with this form? Ok, you'll show name, surname (read only). Then? What a user can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you don't really need any form!
Just pass the `ArrayCollection` to twig, iterate over it and display all values you need. After that, define a route paramized by id that you can access by a link.

So, basically

```
//somewhere in controller
/**
 * @Route("/showSomethingByUserId/{uid}") <-- this could be also inserted into .yml file
 */
public function showSomethingByUserIdAction($uid)
{
    //implement some code to check $uid (just an example)
}
```

Pass `$userpyramid` to twig

```
//somewhere in controller
public function extractAllIdUsersAction()
{
    [...]
    //should be better to create a repository for this
    $id_user = $user->getId();
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('ur','uu')   
        ->from('DtEcBundle:UserReferences', 'ur')
        ->innerJoin("ur.id_user","uu")
        ->where("ur.id_user = :id_user")
        ->setParameter("id_user",$id_user)
        ->getQuery();
    $userpyramid = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('YourBundle:Folder:TwigName.html.twig, array(
        'userPyramid' => $userpyramid)
    );
}
```

Then in your twig

```
{% for user in userpyramid %}
    {{ user.name }}
    {{ user.surname }}
    <a href="{{ path('showSomethingByUserId', {'uid': user.id}) }}">Access to user infos</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course your names may vary accordingly